# onAutoFocus not called in android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I have set the focus mode as FOCUS_MODE_AUTO.

```
camParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
cameraInstance.setParameters(camParameters);
```

Then I have started the preview.

```
cameraInstance.startPreview();
```

After that I am calling the autofocus method.

```
List<String> focusModes = camParameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
                if(focusModes != null && focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Phone supports autofocus!");
                    cameraInstance.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
                }
```

Here is my autofocus callback.

```
private static android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus (boolean success,
                             Camera camera) {
        if(success) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sharp");
            camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Not Sharp");
            camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        }
    }
};
```

I found that the onAutoFocus method is not called after I see the camera preview and noted(in logcat) that the following error is continuously spawning.

01-01 08:29:07.135 765-10897/? **E/mm-camera:  5052: af_port_handle_set_focus_manual_pos_evt: not in CAM_FOCUS_MODE_OFF(Manual) mode,           ignore the settings**

01-01 08:29:07.316 765-10891/? **E/mm-camera:  739: af_process_update_fv_history: SW Stats missing!Start Waiting**

Answer (score 0):

You can try of course, after preview has started. Just call autofocus **inside the surfaceCreated** and it will do the job *when the FOCUS change state*

```
Camera      mCamera;
SurfaceView mPreview;
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0)
     {
     Camera.Parameters     params=mCamera.getParameters();
     params.setFocusMode  (params.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
     mCamera.setParameters(params);
     try
       {
       mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
       mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
       mCamera.startPreview();
       mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback()
              {
              public void onAutoFocus(boolean focussed,Camera camera)
                   {
                   if(focussed)
                     Log.d(TAG, "Sharp");
                     else
                     Log.d(TAG, "Not Sharp");
                   }
              });
       }catch(Exception e){}
```